# JavaScript : How do i set plus or minus 60 days daterange from today?

Tags: javascript, date

I need to pass startdate and enddate parameters to a webservice to fetch the response which range is from plus or minus 60 days from the current date. So what value i need to pass it in the StartDate and EndDate param of javascript? My Client Side App is build on JavaScript/AngularJs.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
var todaysDate = new Date();
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(todaysDate.getDate() - 60);
endDate.setDate(todaysdate.getDate() + 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix timestamp version:

```
var currentUTC = new Date().valueOf()
var sixtyDays = 60*24*60*60*1000
var startDate = currentUTC - sixtyDays
var endDate = currentUTC + sixtyDays
```

Comment: Not all days are 8.64e7 milliseconds long, this doesn't return a Date object and a UNIX "timestamp" is typically seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: @RobG what do you mean not all days are that long? You mean some days are shorter than others?

Comment: Yes. When changing into DST, the day is (usually) 23 hours, when changing out it's 25 hours. A 120 day range has a high probability of crossing one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at momentjs http://momentjs.com/ this is an excellent angular wrapper for moment https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-momentjs. always worth adding to your project when dealing with dates and times

Comment: Saying "use library X" is is not an answer, it should be a comment.